# Tweepy: how do i get info from a tweet when I have its id

Tags: python, tweepy

Im using python and its lybrary Tweepy.
I got some tweets information, like screen_name; followers_count and id_str

question:

Is it possible to get the "extended_text" from a json when I have only the id_str of some tweets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above approach did not work for me.

Try this approach

```
tweet = api.get_status('status_id', tweet_mode="extended")
print(tweet['full_text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

Use `api.get_status(status_id)` to get the tweet data for a specific tweet (`status_id` being the tweet's status ID.

Now to get the JSON from the `api.get_status(status_id)` command, you must add on `._json` to the end, making `api.get_status(status_id)._json.

So I'm assuming you want to get the full text for a tweet now. Note that **there is no `extended_text` variable in any tweet JSON**.

What you're looking for is `full_text` inside `extended_tweet`

So let's try this:

```
tweet_json = api.get_status(status_id)._json
full_tweet = tweet_json['extended_tweet']['full_text']
print(full_tweet)
```

and then you will get the full tweet text using only it's ID

OR if you want the whole `extended_tweet`, not just `full_text`:

```
tweet_json = api.get_status(status_id)._json
extendedtweet = tweet_json['extended_tweet']
```